# Python String Comparison Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I'm new to python so go easy on me here...
In this instance formattedRank = 'N.A.'

```
   if(int(formattedReview) <= 50 and (formattedRank == "N.A.") and (formattedReview == "N.A.")):
        print("hi")
        rank = int(formattedRank)
        review = int(formattedReview)
        totalRank += rank
        totalReviews += rank
        count += 1
```

Error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N.A.'
```

Why might this error be happening I come from a mostly C#, Javascript background so I'm sure a lack of knowledge here is hurting me

Comment: We need you to post enough code to elicit the error you cite.  It seems that formattedReview or formattedRank is a string containing non-digits.

Comment: do you see at the top...i've specified what formattedRank is

Comment: So what do you expect the answer to be. In my mind, you are getting correct behavior. The integer value of the string "N.A." is a ValueError. Were you expecting differently? The string "N.A." is not a valid integer. Nor does it mean anything in Python.

Comment: yes i did its been answered below

Comment: Ignoring the logical fallacies, `if formattedRank == "N.A." and formattedReview == "N.A."` should be sufficient. It would never be <= 50 anyways

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to narrow this down to a minimal example:

```
formattedRank = 'N.A'
int(formattedRank)
```

The `int` function simply does not accept the string `'N.A'`. It doesn't know how to interpret it as an integer, and why should it? It doesn't correspond to any integer.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute ... this isn't possible to pass:

```
if(int(formattedReview) <= 50 and 
      (formattedRank == "N.A.") and 
      (formattedReview == "N.A.")):
```

If formattedReview is the string "N.A.", then it *cannot* convert to an integer, let alone one that is <= 50.  Your logic is faulty ... and I expect that your problematic value of formattedReview has non-digits in the string, which will easily cause the error.